# Hide loader while navigating between webpages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a index.html with a preloader to it. My index.html file is linked 2 more webpages a.html and b.html through a tags. But when i click on link which redirects the user to these webpages and come back to index.html, the preloader again starts animating for x seconds. How can i stop this from happening. I mean i want my preloader only to show up when first opening the site and not when coming back to index.html while navigating.
HTML:

```
<div class="load"></div>
<div id="wrapper"  onload="myFunction()">
            <!--navbar starts-->
            
            <nav id="navbar" >
                <h3>PORTFOLIO</h3>
                <ul id="list">
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="HTML/skills.html">SKILLS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="HTML/projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                    
                </ul>

            </nav>

                


                



                

            </nav>
            <!--navbar ends-->
            <!--Main content-->
            <div id="main">
                <div id="cover-details">
                    <h3>Hallo</h3>
                    <h1 id="main-heading">This is abc!</h1>
                    <h2 id="profession">Im a Web developer.</h2>
                    <p id="college-intro">
                        Competitive coder | Computer Science |
                    </p>

                </div>

                
                
            </div>
            <!--Main content ends-->









    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.load{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/WvuTFk2IN7jxoLVDkP/giphy.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ $('.load').fadeOut('slow'); }, 5000);
 })
```

Comment: Show us the code, then we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save a value after visiting a page and only display the animation if no value is set.

For example:

```js
const visited = localStorage.getItem("visited");

if (!visited) {
  localStorage.setItem("visited", "true");
  $(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ $('.load').fadeOut('slow'); }, 5000);
  })
}
```